# Internal Server Error if logging two events in php

Tags: php, log4php

I use log4php as a logger library. I don't think this issue is related with that library.

I have following code that is giving internal server error:

```
  $log->info("Validando datos de registro de usuario: Nombre: "
          . "$nombre, Apellido: $apellido, Usuario: $usuario, "
          . "Email: $email, Email2: $email2");
  $log->info("Lararala");
```

The curious thing is that the error is not giving in those lines, but after the script, so both events are logged correctly.
If I remove the second line, it works:

```
  $log->info("Validando datos de registro de usuario: Nombre: "
          . "$nombre, Apellido: $apellido, Usuario: $usuario, "
          . "Email: $email, Email2: $email2");
  //$log->info("Lararala");
  //Now Working!
```

It looks like the 2nd logging event is causing something, related to file system that causes an Internal Server Error.

Comment: So _what_ internal server error do you get? What does your http servers error log file say?

Comment: I'm getting error 500, and nothing gets logged !

Comment: Sorry, bit that is not posdible unless you disabled logging. I assume you look at the wrong place. Make sure you know the log files your http Server weites!